# how to write this code without the need of more than one new operator?

Tags: c++, generics, coding-style, new-operator, copy-constructor

I have a generic code with `template <class T>` that I want it to work without the need of `T()`
so for the copy constructor I have this:

```
template <class T>
SortedList<T>::SortedList(const SortedList<T>& list):
  data(new T*[list.max_size])
 ,size(list.size)
 ,max_size(list.max_size)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         T* new_element=new T(*(list.data[i]));//my problem
        data[i]=new_element;
     }
 }
```

and it works fine , and I don't have any valgrind errors or any kind of error
**But** I have learned that it is not good coding to have more than one `new` in your code, so I want to write a code that works without the `new`
so I tried this :

`T* new_element=& T(*(list.data[i]));`

here there is an error :  taking address of temporary

does anyone know what should I do now?

Comment: Where did you learn that strange rule? I haven't heard of it even once in almost 30 years.

Comment: The standard containers (like e.g., `vector`) will allocate large blocks of memory and then fill those blocks in with instances. This is performant, but hard to pull off correctly (and until recently was undefined behavior for anyone but an implementor) What you have is fine; you might prefer a smart pointer instead if you wanted.

Comment: @molbdnilo  in university they may even take points down from my homework if I do that

Comment: That rule reminds me of "always auto ampersand ampersand" rule XD That's out of crazy idea rules.Two-dimensional canot be done with single new, but you  may emulate it

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie thank you for reminding me about how Two dimensional would have more than one `new` , I sent a message to the instructors and used it as an example, I hope they understand and say it's fine to do it this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this:

```
template <class T>
SortedList<T>::SortedList(const SortedList<T>& list):
  data(new T*[list.max_size])
 ,size(list.size)
 ,max_size(list.max_size)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         T* new_element=new T(*(list.data[i]));
        data[i]=new_element;
     }
 }
```

You are copying all the elements of the other `SortedList<T>`. I am not sure where you heard this:

> I have learned that it is not good coding to have more than one new in your code.

It **is** a good practice to stay away from dynamic allocation and use pre-coded containers. From the sound of `SortedList`, I'd say you want a `std::set` instead.

If it is acceptable for your container to use the other container's elements, you can do this:

```
template <class T>
SortedList<T>::SortedList(const SortedList<T>& list):
  data(new T*[list.max_size])
 ,size(list.size)
 ,max_size(list.max_size)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         T* new_element= list.data[i];
        data[i]=new_element;
     }
 }
```

This could **pose some problems**, because if you modify the first `SortedList<T>`'s elements, it would modify the second's, so you probably don't want to do this.

The reason you cannot do this:

```
T* new_element=& T(*(list.data[i]));
```

Is because `*list.data[i]` is a temporary variable, and it is destructed as soon as you exit the current iteration of the `for` loop. If you take it's address, as soon as you try to modify it, you will get an error, as the element does no longer exist. (It has been destructed.) I would recommend that you keep your code the same for now, or even better, use a different container.

Another answer to this question proposes using this:

```
std::memcpy(data, list.data, list.size * sizeof(T))
```

The problem with this, is, as @AndyG stated:

> Gotta be really careful with something like this. It will only work for trivially relocatable types, not generic T.

The other answer also proposed doing `std::copy`. This may work for your purpose, as it is higher level, and does all the work with `new` behind the scenes. To use it, you would do this:

```
std::copy(list.data[0], list.data[list.size-1], data[0]);
```

Comment: if I keep my code the same , do I have to check if a `bad_alloc` was thrown from new and then delete all the memory that is already allocated in the function?

Comment: @raghad it would be a good practice, yes. Also, note the `std::copy` in the latest edit, it may be better for you.

Comment: TIL "hiddenly" is a word. :)

Comment: @WillNess you can adverb many adjectives if the word doesn't end with "ly" without being adverb (e.g. ugly, silly) or are getting a word with different meaning when "ly" is added (e.g. "hardly")

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie just never heard or seen it used before. :)